# Compare 2 lists

Tags: c#

I will do my best to explain my headache here.

I've got 2 generic lists that contain the same type and therefore same type of fields:

```
List<Car> car1 = GetCars1();
List<Car> car2 = GetCars2();
List<Car> finalListOfCars2 = new List<Car>();
```

so Car has a field called BumperTypeID

I want to compare list car1 with car2 and find those cars from car2 where car2[index].BumperTypeID exists in the list of all BumperTypeIDs in car1's list of BumperTypeIDs.  If it's found in car1's list of BumperTypeIDs, great...  But I need to then do another check after this to check that ColorIsBlack.  And if that second check turns out true, then ok we're good, add the current car2[index] to the finalList.

So I am not sure how to go about this honestly.  It's giving me a headache just thinking about it.  It's probably not as bad as I think but I can't wrap my head around a good way to approach this in code.

Comment: Can you show what code you have so far? I'm struggling to understand exactly what you are working with.

Comment: let me break this down again.  Both lists have this ID I want to check for. I need to do like an intersection...give me a list back of the IDs where they are found in both lists. However the main caveat and problem, is that per each match, I need to do some further processing. So if I find ID 4 in both lists, ok fine, but I need to then do another check for something else because I did find that to match...how to interject another set of logic in between each hunt and find whatever ID in both lists is the problem

Comment: so before you give me the matched list back, I need to do something additional in terms of logic..I need to do another check (like a sub check) after every time I find a match to determine if I should really include this in the final list outcome

Comment: So it's like:  1) loop through and do an intersection 2) at each match do something else and if that something else is good/bad then invalidate or validate it again to determine whether to keep it in the intersected list.

Comment: I haven't coded it yet cause I can't figure out a good way to do this.  My head hurts trying to figure out a decent way to approach this.

Comment: Why not to use a simple foreach loop for matching and processing?

Comment: I can use a foreach...but I am not sure how to take each MyCustomType2.SomeID and check that it exists in all of MyCUstomType1's SomeIDs.

Comment: I updated the post entirely to explain this again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly clear on what you're looking for overall, but to compare a List to a List you can use the `Intersect<T>()` extension method.  It will return a list of all the items that exist in both lists.

If you're looking for items that exist in one list but not the other, use the `Except<T>()` method.

EDIT: Based on your edits, your code would look something like this:

```
public void CompareLists(List<Car> carList1, List<car> carList2){
    var car1Ids = carList1.Select(l => l.BumperTypeID);
    var car2Ids = carList2.Select(l => l.BumperTypeID);

    // Find all cars in List2 that have matching BumperTypeID's
    // and filter it that list further based on the color.
    var matchedIds = car2Ids.Intersect(car1Ids).Where(x => x.Color == Color.Black);

    // do your work here.
}
```

This is the method I've used elsewhere for merging lists of items.  You can refer to my [answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644914/reconciling-two-collections-of-objects/1645092#1645092) for further details on it.

EDIT2: Based on your updated question, I've updated the code.  This assumes that there's a unique list of BumperTypeIDs in the collection.  I think you're solution will be a mixture of this solution with [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847898/compare-2-lists/1847979#1847979).

Comment: ok but how can I do some logic if lest say myList1.SomeID is found in all of the SomeIDs in mylist2?  I need to do an extra check after I find a match is what I'm saying.  So whenever I find a match where one is in the other or vice versa, do something, then move on to the next match found and do something

Comment: Based on all your comments it's still not quite clear what your looking for.  Are you looking to compare the 2 lists based on multiple properties/fields of the objects in both lists?  So if both lists have equal SomeID and equal Field1 and equal Field2 then it should be considered an equal match?

Comment: no not quite.  I'm going to update my original post. Hold on.

Comment: omg, that's amazing.  I am not really into Lambda yet but man, I can see the power in this!

Comment: how would I replace x.Color with a method call?

Comment: the method call would return a bool

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is right, Linq can make finding the intersection of two lists pretty easy.  Use the [Intersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx) method, and pass in your own custom IEqualityComparer which compares two objects in the list to determine if they are the same.

You can then iterate over the intersection of the two sets.  For more information about all of the different "Set" operators (Union, Intersect, Except, etc), look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx).

Edit:

To add additional filters, just chain additional Linq operators onto this query.  For example:

```
IDList1.Intersects(IdList2, MyIdComparer).Where(entry => entry.SomethingINeedToCheck == true);
```

Edit Again:

Here is the above clause, but updated for your new edit:

```
var ResultList = cars1.Intersects(cars2, CarIdComparer).Where(car => car.IsColorBlack).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, I think now is the time for me to start Lambda and LINQ...wow.

Answer (score 0):

**IComparer** is the way to go.