# Best way to compare two large string lists, using C# and LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a large list (~ 110,000 strings), which I need to compare to a similar sized list.

List A comes from 1 system.
List B comes from a SQL table (I can only read, no stored procs, etc)

What is the best way to find what values are in list A, that no longer exists in list B?

Is 100,000 strings a large number to be handled in an array?

thanks

Comment: When you say list b comes from a sql table, does this mean that list b is loaded into memory, or is it something like a sql reader dataset where you can only see one item at a time?

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQL for your list b?

Comment: I'm using a tableadapter, so it's in memory for the SQL table data (List B).
List A I was reading into an ArrayList, but could use List<string>.

Comment: Does order matter?  That is, do we know, for instance, that both lists are in the same order, but that list B might have some missing?  Could list B have items which are NOT in list A? There are ways to optimize this operation if you can constrain the problem to lists that have nice properties.

Comment: Order does not matter.  I just need to see what is in list A that is not in list B.

Comment: Suppose list A is "X, Y, Z".  Can list B be "Z, X" ?  Or will it always be "X, Z" -- that is, the same items, same *order*, but some missing? It is much easier to detect missing items in a long list if you know that the two lists are in the same order.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So you have two lists like so:

```
List<string> listA;
List<string> listB;
```

Then use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
List<string> except = listA.Except(listB).ToList();
```

Note that if you want to, say, ignore case:

```
List<string> except = listA.Except(listB, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

You can replace the last parameter with an [`IEqualityComparer<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) of your choosing.

Answer (score 9):

With LINQ:

```
var missing = listA.Except(listB).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice. Similar to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx

I'm not used to dealing with large datasets, so is 100,000 easily handled this way?

Comment: Sure; and if it isn't, you're going to have to work at the db, so C# is out anyway ;-p

Answer (score 6):

Out of interest, do you HAVE to use `List<string>`? Because in .net 3.5 SP1, you can use the [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) and it's [ExceptWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx) method. To my understanding, HashSets are specifically optimized for comparisons between two Sets.

Comment: No don't have to use List<string>.  I will take a look at HashSet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> A = //get from file
List<string> B = //get from db

var C = A.Except(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

Stealing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847898/compare-2-lists), it looks like you could use the `Except<T>()` method.