# Compare two generic lists and remove duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have two generic Lists, one called "Featured" and the other called "Filtered".

```
List<Content> Featured = new List<Content>();
List<Content> Filtered = new List<Content>();
```

Both contain "Content" items which are simple classes like so :

```
public class Content
{
    public long ContentID { get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Teaser { get; set; }

    public Content(long contentId, string title, string url, string image, string teaser)
    {
        ContentID = contentId;
        Title = title;
        Url = url;
        Image = image;
    }
}
```

Any items that appear in "Filtered" but also appear in "Featured" need to be removed from "Filtered".  Additionally, both lists will then be combined into a single generic list with the "Featured" items appearing first.

I know I could write a couple of foreach loops to do this but I can't help feel there must be a more elegant method using LINQ.

I am using C# 4.0.

Comment: So, `Featured` should appear in its entirety, and then `Filtered`, but with any items from `Featured` removed?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2060093/100283. It isn't Linq but it is a easy way of comparing the two objects.

Comment: How do you compare `Contents`, what makes them unique?

Comment: The ContentID property is unique

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an IEqualityComparer defined you can use the `Union` method:

```
List<Content> FeaturedAndFiltered = Featured.Union(Filtered, new MyContentComparer());
```

A rough implementation of MyContentComparer would be:

```
public class ContentEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Content>
{

    public bool Equals(Content c1, Content c2)
    {
        return (c1.ContentID == c2.ContentID);
    }


    public int GetHashCode(Content c)
    {
        return c.ContentID.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the LINQ method `Union`, specifically

```
var singleList = Featured.Union(Filtered);
```

This will return all the `Featured` items, followed by all the `Filtered` items that were not `Featured`. Note that it will *also* remove any duplicates *within* a list - so if an item is `Featured` twice, it will only show up *once*.

You do, however, need to be able to *compare* instances of `Content` in order to do this, either by adding in implementations of `Equal` and `GetHashCode` or by providing an `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the objects presenter in both lists are the actual same objects, you can do the following:

```
var totalList = Featured
    .Concat(Filtered.Where(f => !Featured.Contains(f)))
    .ToList()
```

**Update**

Or, using the Except method as mentioned by Mahmoud Gamal:

```
var totalList = Featured
    .Concat(Filtered.Except(Featured))
    .ToList()
```