# Best way to compare list of tuples

Tags: c#

I have two lists populated from different sources, what is the best way to check if both list contains the same items? Order is not important

```
List<Tuple<string, string, string>> list1;
List<Tuple<string, string, string>> list2;
```

Comment: so your check should return `true`, if they contain exactly the same items but possibly in different order? Or is it ok if one has more items?

Comment: The "best" way is only something you can decide, not us. Have you tried to figure this out for yourself yet? What did you try? Show that code please, we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060058/best-way-to-compare-two-large-string-lists-using-c-sharp-and-linq?rq=1

Comment: @RenéVogt there is a difference between strings and tuples, though. But I agree that the general approach is the same, you just need to provide a comparer

Comment: @FlorianKoch but not a difference that matters here, the default equality comparer for tuples uses the default equality comparer for all its elements. The question here is only how to compare lists, the type of the list elements doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `!Except.Any`:

```
bool same = list1.Count == list2.Count && !list1.Except(list2).Any();
```

Explanation:

1. check if both lists have the same `Count`, otherwise you know they don't contain the same
2. then check with `Except` and `Any` if there are remeaining tuples if you "remove" `list2` from `list1`. If there are `Any`(at least one) you know they don't contain the same

Works because tuples override [`GetHashCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd414894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)(like anonymous types too) and `string` too.

Comment: Please provide at least a short explanation of how and why this code works.

Comment: @FlorianKoch: added, does that make sense?

Comment: yeah, perfect (:

Comment: Except performance in o(n+m) as per this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269610/how-does-except-method-work-in-linq