# Comparing large list

Tags: c#

I have two very Lage lists, a few hundred thousand items per list, one is complete and the other one hast missing items. I need to know which items are missing in the incomplete list. I‘ve already tried using `Enumerable.Except` but it takes ages until they are fully compared.

Comment: maybe you should use HashSets instead of Lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to compare two large string lists, using C# and LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060058/best-way-to-compare-two-large-string-lists-using-c-sharp-and-linq)

Comment: In addition to what @kriss has said, do you have any special partitioning logic specific to your data that might help you to break the problem into smaller sub-problems. For example, a sorted list is easier to compare, or a continuous range of numbers with some missing numbers are easy to find

Comment: Both list are sorted alphabetically

Comment: @Unex are they list of strings? also, please define 'missing item', missing in left, right, either?

Comment: @vc 74 yes, they are.

Comment: are the strings pretty long? Do you end up running against memory issues?

Comment: @Vikhram The strings are 17 Charakters Long, and all Look like this :“POS0001:615155172“ just with different Numbers for every string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var incompleteSet = new HashSet<string>(incompleteList);

IEnumerable<string> missing = completeList.Where(str => !incompleteSet.Contains(str));
```

But the same mechanism is roughly used in `Enumerable.Except` so I don't think it will make performance better. Did you compile in release or debug config?

Comment: if he can use HashSet from the beginning it is better to do so, no need to create Linq.Set before comparation

Comment: @kriss What do you mean "Linq.Set"?

Comment: I meant Linq implementation of Set in System.Linq.Set, which is created from the List on which you are calling Except

Comment: It actually went a lot quicker with this method, thanks, but it does still take quite a while. I also usually compile in release.

Comment: @Unex Then I'm afraid there's not much you can do to make it quicker (on this machine...)

Comment: @vc74 ok, that’s fine. But thanks for helping. It did improve the performance quite a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have provided, I think you should be able to get good performance benefits by transforming your string into integral type before comparison.

I have written the LINQ and non LINQ versions of the implementation. The main difference is that the `.ToDictionary` call will be slightly slower, due to re-allocation of bigger memory slots. In the non-LINQ version we can use a `HashSet`, but the version I use (`4.6.1`) does not allow me to construct by specifying the capacity.

```
// Sample String POS0001:615155172
static long GetKey(string s) => long.Parse("1" + s.Substring(3, 4) + s.Substring(8));
static IEnumerable<string> FindMissing(IEnumerable<string> masterList, ICollection<string> missingList) {
    var missingSet = new Dictionary<long, bool>(missingList.Count);
    foreach (string s in missingList)
        missingSet.Add(GetKey(s), true);

    // Compact LINQ Way, but potentially, ineffecient
    //var missingSet = missingList.ToDictionary(GetKey, s => true);

    return masterList.Where(s => !missingSet.ContainsKey(GetKey(s)));
}
```

There are, slightly more involved, single-pass ways to solve your problem, since your data is already sorted. Let me know if this works for you or not, as I don't have a test bed to test this.